# jQuery .nextAll() is not working with html table columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table as below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On click of a td I am changing the color of it's next 4 td's and for that I have done it in jquery as below:

```
$(this).nextAll("td").slice(0, 4).addClass("selected");
```

Above code is working if I click on 1st TD then it selects further 4 td's but if I click on 4th td then it selects only 5th td. I want it to select another 3 td's in next row as well.

Please tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: From http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/ "Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector."

The important thing to not is that it gets all following siblings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery `.index()` method returns the index of passed element in the current set. By using returned index you can `.slice()` the collection, this is more efficient than querying the DOM on each click, especially when you have a big table:

```
var $tds = $('#table td').on('click', function() {
   var i = $tds.index(this);
   $tds.slice(++i, i+4).addClass("selected");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MamYX/

Comment: @dystroy Yes, misread the question, updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: Hm, maybe `$('td:gt(' + $tds.index(this) + '):lt(4)')` is even better...?

Comment: @VisioN  Why is that better? Traversing the DOM using string selectors can't be more efficient that manipulating cached set, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add the `td` of the following row. :

```
$(this).nextAll("td").add($(this).closest('tr').nextAll().find('td'))
       .slice(0, 4).addClass("selected");
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/EWOQIGE/1/)

Comment: This worked for me and it is also good because it is a single line solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Update: this method is failing in case of multiple rows, if I would have to select 10 td which are across multiple rows then it is not working, so unmarked as answer instead the method given by @undefined is working no matter how many td's you have on the page.

Comment: @Prashant I answered your question, not a more general one. For a more general one use `nextAll` instead of `next`.

Comment: Thanks dystroy: Yes, it is working fine with `nextAll` for a single table, but in case of multiple tables and if I have to select continue td's then I have to add code for "table" same as you have done for tr. I think instead it is better to find all tds and then select then select the required tds.

Comment: @Prashant As you want. I have nothing against the other solution, I even updated it ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
var $tds = $('table td').click(function(){
    var idx = $tds.index(this);
    $tds.filter(':gt(' + idx + '):lt(4)').addClass('selected')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jhMYZ/)